# MoveFileEx - returning GetLastError(): 17

Tags: c++, winapi, movefileex

I'm using MoveFileEx to move a file. depending on what the user inputs, where it moves the files might be on a seperate hard drive. under this circumstance MoveFileEx fails with GetLastError reporting error ID 17, which is:

> ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE 17 (0x11) The system cannot move the file to a
>   different disk drive.
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

so, how, in VC++ would I go about handling a situation like this, and move the file, even if it's on a seperate hard drive?

the code I'm using is here: https://gist.github.com/Whitetigerswt/9180030 (although it's not relevant I think, everything works great except when moving files to another hard drive.)

Answer (score 12):

The documentation for [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) makes this clear:

> When moving a file, the destination can be on a different file system or volume. **If the destination is on another drive, you must set the MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED flag in dwFlags.**

So if the source drive is not the same as the destination drive, simply or the `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` flag into `dwFlags`.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the solution suggested by you and I got ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED 5 (0x5). Any suggestions? I get the error if the file already exists, however I'm interested in performing a proper move operation.